# Integral $\int \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)(1+\sin(x))}dx$ is or is not $\ln (\sin(x))$ + $\ln (\sin(x)+1)$

Tags: integration

> Evaluate
>   $$\int \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)(1+\sin(x))}dx$$

I was attempting this integral and I keep getting the answer of $\ln (\sin(x))$ + $\ln (\sin(x)+1)$

I have looked on websites and keep receiving different answers. I was wondering how to compute this integral, and what the answer would be. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your answer there should be a minus sign.
\begin{align*}\int \frac{\cos(x)}{\sin(x)(1+\sin(x))}dx&=\int \frac{1}{\sin(x)(1+\sin(x))} d(\sin(x))\\&=\int \left(\frac{1}{\sin(x)}-\frac{1}{1+\sin(x)} \right)d(\sin(x))\\&= \ln(|\sin(x)|) - \ln(1+\sin(x))+C\\&=\ln\left(\frac{|\sin(x)|}{1+\sin(x)}\right)+C.
\end{align*}

Answer (score 1):

Hint -

Put $\sin x = t$

On differentiate,

$\cos x \,dx = \,dt$

Put these values in above,

$\int \frac{\,dt}{t(1+t)}$

= $\int \frac{1}t - \frac 1{1+t} \,dt$

Now integrate.